# trigger to populate Contact lookup on custom object

Tags: apex, trigger, code

I have a custom object, `Deal_Reg__c`. On this object, i have a Contact lookup field, `Submitter_Contact__c`. I would like the trigger to populate this Submitter_Contact__c field. The trigger will fire when the `Status` field on the Deal_Reg__c is changed to **Submit**.

In order to populate the Submitter_Contact__c field, the user will change the Status field to "Submit" and the field will populate with the current user's contact.

My thought is that i will need to use the LastModifiedBy field on Deal_Reg__c to get the current User, and then from there get the Contact. Here is what i currently have which is not working properly:

```
trigger UpdateDealSubmitterContact on Deal_Reg__c (before Update) {

    list<id> oid = new list<id>();
    User user;
    for(Deal_Reg__c o: trigger.new){                   
        oid.add(o.id);
    }

    for(Deal_Reg__c o: trigger.new){
        if(o.Deal_Registration_Status__c == 'Submit') {
            map<id, Deal_Reg__c> ExtendU = new map<id, Deal_Reg__c>(
                [select LastModifiedByID from Deal_Reg__c where id in: oid]);
            user = [select ContactID from User where id =: ExtendU.get(o.id).LastModifiedBy.Id];

            //o.Submitter_Contact__c = ExtendU.get(o.id).LastModifiedBy.ContactID;
            o.Submitter_Contact__c = user.ContactID;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Current user means the user currently logged in is it?

Comment: Yes, the user currently logged in

Answer (score 2):

Few suggestions

1. You should avoid using [`SOQL` inside `for` loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops).
2. Here is my code / trigger that I would use to fulfill the requirement you specified above (plz understand by reading [apex best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)).

   ```
   trigger UpdateDealSubmitterContact on Deal_Reg__c (before Update) {
       // populate user ids 
       Set<Id> UserIds = new Set<Id>();
       for (Deal_Reg__c dReg : Trigger.new) 
           UserIds.add(dReg.LastModifiedBy);

       // get the contacts against the userids 
       map<id, user> userContact = 
                   new map<id, user>([SELECT user.Id , user.Contact.id, user.name
                                      FROM User
                                      WHERE user.id IN:UserIds]);

       // check and update submitter contact
       for(Deal_Reg__c o: trigger.new){
           if(o.Deal_Registration_Status__c == 'Submit') {
               o.Submitter_Contact__c = userContact.get(o.LastModifiedById).Contact.Id;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the response. I actually plugged in the code you sent and got the following error: Error: Compile Error: Incompatible element type SOBJECT:User for collection of Id at line 5 column 9

In order to get around the error i changed both "LastModifiedBy" to "LastModifiedById". This allows the code to compile but doesn't populate the Submitter_Contact__c field with anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RayRay: you need to check whether there is any contact against the logged-in user. The reason you are not getting any `ContactId` might be that there is no contact against the user you are looking.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the current user. See ([UserInfo documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm)).

Try Userinfo.getuserid()